# primefaces data table from hibernate select not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

so the intention was jsf+hibernate integration .so when every time we run the program hibernate should execute the select from table name and that values should be populated in the primefaces data table

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="solodemo")
public class solodemo {
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public solodemo(String fname, String lanme) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lanme = lanme;
    }
    public String getLanme() {
        return lanme;
    }
    public void setLanme(String lanme) {
        this.lanme = lanme;
    }
    solodemo(){}
    @Column(name="fname")
    @Id
    private String fname;
    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lanme;



}
```

hibernate pojo class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import hibernate.Util;
@ManagedBean(name="datafromtable")
@RequestScoped
public class Solomain {
private ArrayList<solodemo> list;
    public ArrayList<solodemo> getList() {
    return list;
}
public void setList(ArrayList<solodemo> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
    public ArrayList<solodemo> init(){
Session sn=Util.getSessionFactory().openSession();
sn.beginTransaction();


Query qry=sn.createQuery(" from solodemo p");


 list=new ArrayList<solodemo>(qry.list());



System.out.println("yo bitch you have done it");
return  list;
    }

}
```

this is the managed bean

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
<title>DATA TABLES DEMO</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<h1>output values</h1>
<p:dataTable value="#{datafromtable.list}"  var="so">

<p:column headerText="firstname">
<h:outputText value="#{so.fname}"/>

</p:column>
<p:column  headerText="lanme">

<h:outputText value="#{so.lname}"/>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

this is the xhtml file every time i run this file this should go to managed bean then select query should fetch the data from data base and it should be populated in datatable.but hibernate query is not executing so it returns null value in data table any way to rectify this problem

Comment: since i used annotation there was no hbm.xml file

Answer (score -1):

i got the result after doing the following changes

```
public ArrayList<Solodemo> init(){
Session sn=Util.getSessionFactory().openSession();
sn.beginTransaction();


Query qry=sn.createQuery("from Solodemo");


ArrayList<Solodemo> list= new ArrayList<Solodemo>(qry.list());
```

and in the xhtml file

```
<p:dataTable value="#{data.init()}"  var="so">
```